# How can I make FFA server in OSP which anyone can join even during match

Tags: quake-3

When I create server in OSP mod, anyone can join the game during warmup. But after the game has been started, new players can't join the game, server says something like "You can join the game after the current match ends". How can I disable this?

I don't have this problem in baseq3.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that OSP is designed for competitive play, there doesn't appear to be a named option to enable the ability to join a team during an active round, you could try setting FFA rather than FFA (Competitive) and see if this allows you to join a game during a live round - you can do this using the 'vote' options in game provided you have `server_availmodes` set to a value that allows it

Comment: @pixel Thanks for answer. But how can I set FFA rather than FFA (Competitive)? I have `g_gametype 0`, isn't FFA? `server_availmodes` returns 127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you need is `match_latejoin`. Set it to `1` to allow players to join.

Or you could just set `g_dowarmup` to `0`. This disables warmup mode, so the game will start immediately and `match_latejoin` parameter will be ignored (so it will be more like baseq3 FFA).